# How do I keep ground turkey or chicken from clumping when I cook it?

Tags: chicken, turkey, texture

When I sautee ground turkey or chicken for tacos or sloppy joes, I want the chunks of meat to be smaller and more like ground beef which breaks up easily.  But the ground turkey or chicken tends to form clumps and not break into a uniform texture.  Does anyone have any suggestions for getting smaller and more even chunks of ground turkey or chicken?

Answer (score 2):

Add a little water to the skillet with the meat. Figure about 1/4 cup of water per pound of meat. Stir and chop the chunks vigorously in the beginning, then brown as normal. As the water evaporates, the chicken or turkey will brown as if the water was never there, but the texture will fine and uniform.